# При нажатии на бургер меню ничего не происходит

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, scss

Проверял несколько раз, вроде бы с синтаксисом всё в порядке. Может, что-то не заметил.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.header__burger').click(function(event) {
    $('.header__burger, .header__menu').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
/* Header */

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.fullscreen {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1710px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 50;
}

.header:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.header__body {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 80px;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__logo {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  @include adaptiv-font(25, 15);
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #ffffff;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

.header__logo {
  padding: 20px;
}

.header__logo img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.header__burger {
  display: none;
}

.header__list {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.header__list li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px 30px 0px 60px;
}

.header__link {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  @include adaptiv-font(20, 15);
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header__link:hover {
  transition: width 0.3s ease-out;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.header__link:after {
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  /*изменить на right:0;, чтобы изменить направление подчёркивания */
  width: 0;
  /*задаём длинну линии до наведения курсора*/
  height: 2px;
  /*задаём ширину линии*/
  background-color: #ffffff;
  /*задаём цвет линии*/
  content: "";
  transition: width 0.3s ease-out;
  /*задаём время анимации*/
}

.header__link:hover:after,
.header__link:focus:after {
  width: 100%;
  /*устанавливаем значение 100% чтобы ссылка подчёркивалась полностью*/
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  body.lock {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .header__body {
    height: 50px;
  }
  .header__logo {
    flex: 0 0 40px;
  }
  .header__burger {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    z-index: 3;
  }
  .header__burger span {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    top: 9px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  }
  .header__burger:before,
  .header__burger:after {
    content: "";
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  }
  .header__burger:before {
    top: 0;
  }
  .header__burger:after {
    bottom: 0;
  }
  .header__burger.active span {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  .header__burger.active:before {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 9px;
  }
  .header__burger.active:after {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    bottom: 9px;
  }
  .header__menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: -100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    background-color: #18b5a4;
    padding: 70px 10px 20px 10px;
  }
  .header__menu.active {
    top: 0;
  }
  .header__list {
    display: block;
  }
  .header__list li {
    margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
  }
  .header__link {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper" id="header">
  <div class="fullscreen">
    <header class="header">
      <div class='container'>
        <div class="header__body">
          <a href="#" class="header__logo">
            <div>GK.</div>
          </a>
          <div class="header__burger">
            <span></span>
          </div>
          <nav class="header__menu">
            <ul class="header__list">
              <li>
                <a href="#home" class="header__link">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#about" class="header__link">About</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#works" class="header__link">Team</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#service" class="header__link">Service</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#contact" class="header__link">Contact</a>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="content">
      <div class='container'>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: в маленьком окне работает вроде, но выглядит как то не очень

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если убрать медиазапрос то работает при любой ширине экрана

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.header__burger').click(function(event) {
    $('.header__burger, .header__menu').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
/* Header */

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.fullscreen {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1710px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 50;
}

.header:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.header__body {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 80px;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__logo {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  @include adaptiv-font(25, 15);
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #ffffff;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

.header__logo {
  padding: 20px;
}

.header__logo img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.header__burger {
  display: none;
}

.header__list {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.header__list li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px 30px 0px 60px;
}

.header__link {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  @include adaptiv-font(20, 15);
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header__link:hover {
  transition: width 0.3s ease-out;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.header__link:after {
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  /*изменить на right:0;, чтобы изменить направление подчёркивания */
  width: 0;
  /*задаём длинну линии до наведения курсора*/
  height: 2px;
  /*задаём ширину линии*/
  background-color: #ffffff;
  /*задаём цвет линии*/
  content: "";
  transition: width 0.3s ease-out;
  /*задаём время анимации*/
}

.header__link:hover:after,
.header__link:focus:after {
  width: 100%;
  /*устанавливаем значение 100% чтобы ссылка подчёркивалась полностью*/
}

/*@media (max-width: 767px) {*/
  body.lock {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .header__body {
    height: 50px;
  }
  .header__logo {
    flex: 0 0 40px;
  }
  .header__burger {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    z-index: 3;
  }
  .header__burger span {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    top: 9px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  }
  .header__burger:before,
  .header__burger:after {
    content: "";
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  }
  .header__burger:before {
    top: 0;
  }
  .header__burger:after {
    bottom: 0;
  }
  .header__burger.active span {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  .header__burger.active:before {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 9px;
  }
  .header__burger.active:after {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    bottom: 9px;
  }
  .header__menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: -100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    background-color: #18b5a4;
    padding: 70px 10px 20px 10px;
  }
  .header__menu.active {
    top: 0;
  }
  .header__list {
    display: block;
  }
  .header__list li {
    margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
  }
  .header__link {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
/*}*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper" id="header">
  <div class="fullscreen">
    <header class="header">
      <div class='container'>
        <div class="header__body">
          <a href="#" class="header__logo">
            <div>GK.</div>
          </a>
          <div class="header__burger">
            <span></span>
          </div>
          <nav class="header__menu">
            <ul class="header__list">
              <li>
                <a href="#home" class="header__link">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#about" class="header__link">About</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#works" class="header__link">Team</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#service" class="header__link">Service</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#contact" class="header__link">Contact</a>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="content">
      <div class='container'>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Проблема решена.,Была подключена не та библиотека. Я подключил твою и заработало, но медиа запрос я не убирал.